# sort.Search, looking for a number that is not in the slice

Tags: go

I currently have a problem in my project where i must find numbers that are **not** present in a slice. I found working code in the [golang](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search) website, this works great. In my project i make a empty block and let the else statement do all the work. I tried to alter the code to remove the empty block but i got errors every time, i finaly found a example that reproduces the problem :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    data := []int{27, 15, 8, 9, 12, 4, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25}
    nr := 9
    sort.Ints(data)
    index := sort.Search(len(data), func(index int) bool { return data[index] == nr })
    if index == len(data) {
        fmt.Print("It's not in : ")
        fmt.Println(nr)
    } else {
        fmt.Print("It's in! Index is at : ")
        fmt.Println(index)
    }
}
```

Working code on golang [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1Ju6BaqtTe)!

Comment: I think you want `func(index int) bool { return data[index] >= nr }`.

Comment: @4of4 That would create the same as the original code i currently have with the empty block. The documentation says that == is allowed and that the index = len(data) when it's not found. But somehow, it's not working.

Comment: I probably don't understand the question. What output are you expecting from your example program?

Comment: @4of4 If you check the golang playground link, you see that 9 is in the slice but sort.search tells that it's not in. If you try to find for 27, it works correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    data := []int{27, 15, 8, 9, 12, 4, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25}
    sort.Ints(data)
    fmt.Println(data)
    x := 9
    notpresent := false
    i := sort.Search(len(data), func(i int) bool { return data[i] >= x })
    if i >= len(data) || data[i] != x {
        // x is not present in data,
        // but i is the index where it would be inserted.
        notpresent = true
    }
    fmt.Println(x, notpresent)
}
```

Output:

```
[4 8 9 12 15 17 19 21 23 25 27]
9 false
```

Answer (score 5):

I encounter the same problem too, because I misunderstood the document in `godoc sort Search`.

> If the caller wants to find whether 23 is in the slice, it must test data[i] == 23 separately.

I thought that means "The documentation says that == is allowed" too. In fact, in the function as a parameter in sort.Search, can only use `>=` or `<=`, no `==`. And that sentence means after you got the index `i`, you have to test it with `data[i] == 23` to make sure 23 is in the slice.